# Inserting HTML content into a Vue Tooltip

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, tooltip

I'm trying to render a tooltip for a table cell in Vue, for when the table cell's content exceeds 22 characters.

I need to use the v-tooltip library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-tooltip)

I can set the content of the tooltip to a simple string correctly using the 'content' attribute, however, when I try to set the html content, the tooltip is blank, and the html content which was supposed to appear inside the tooltip, appears constantly in the td.

```
<td v-if="cellContent !== null && cellContent.length>22">
        <div>
            <!-- <span v-tooltip.right="{content: 'This works, but is just a simple string', class:'mytooltip'}">{{cellContent.substring(0, 19)}}...</span> -->
            <span class="icon-info-outline" v-tooltip.right="{ html: 'wildcardContent', class:'mytooltip' }"></span>
            <div id="wildcardContent">
                <p>This Fails and is displayed in the td</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>                        
    <td v-else >{{cellContent }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v-tooltip="{ content: `<h1>Hellow World</h1>` }"
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use a function that returns the html code or variable that has html. Just call it inside the content. use this in making html code ``

Answer (score 0):

Use escape option:
https://primevue.org/tooltip/#api.tooltip.interfaces.TooltipOptions.escape

```
<span  v-tooltip.top="{escape: false, value: !isMovie ?
                '<span class=\'white-space-nowrap font-bold\'>Series</span><br>' :
                '<span class=\'white-space-nowrap font-bold\'>Movie</span><br>'
          }"

</span>
```